# Nestjs cannot receives uploads image

Tags: https, upload, nestjs, nest

I have a question because I've been stuck on a problem for 2 days.

Put into context: I have an angular + nginx container and a nestjs container which manages my backend.
As well as a couchdb container which manages my posts

My problem occurs in https.
I recover the data but not the images.

I got this error on my page : https://url/api/uploads/img_name

```
{"statusCode":404,"message":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/uploads/index.html'"}
```

Everyone can tell me if you think it's a problem with my backend or my nginx or server configuration ?

Thanks for help

My posts.controller

```
async getAllPosts(): Promise<ExtendedPost[]> {
try {
      const result = await this.couchdbService.db.list({ include_docs: true });
      const posts: ExtendedPost[] = result.rows.map((row) => {
        const post = row.doc as unknown as ExtendedPost; // Cast le document en ExtendedPost
        // Ajoute le chemin complet de l'image au post
        post.imagePath = `https://MYURL/api/uploads${post.imagePath}`; // Remplace avec l'URL correcte
        return post;
      });
      return posts;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new NotFoundException('Error fetching posts');
    }
  }
```

And in my main.ts i got that :

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule, {cors: true});

  app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, '..', 'uploads'), {
    prefix: '/uploads/',  // Assurez-vous que le préfixe correspond au chemin dans vos URLs
    index: false
  });

  await app.listen(3000);
}
```